# WordPress $wpdb->options returns blank

Tags: class, function, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress theme and trying to use the $wpdb class from within my own theme class. When I try to use the following SQL query the `$wpdb->options` variable is blank and generates an error.

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query("UPDATE ". $wpdb->options ." SET option_value = 'a:0:{}' WHERE option_name = 'active_plugins';");
```

I am using this code within a class I have created.

Here is a highly scaled down sample of the class

```
class Theme_Class {

    function init($options) {

        /* Load theme's functions. */
        $this->functions();

    }

    function plugins() {
        global $wpdb;

        /* Auto plugin activation */
        if(get_option('morphius_int_plugins', '0') == '0') {

            $wpdb->query("UPDATE ". $wpdb->options ." SET option_value = 'a:0:{}' WHERE option_name = 'active_plugins';");
            $wpdb->query("UPDATE ". $wpdb->sitemeta ." SET meta_value = 'a:0:{}' WHERE meta_key = 'active_plugins';");
            update_option('morphius_int_plugins', '1');
        }

    }
}
```

Am I not globalizing the $wpdb variable properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

From what I could figure out so far. It seems to be te quotes in the SQL syntax that is causing the issue. If I change the query to

```
$wpdb->query("UPDATE $wpdb->options SET option_value = 'a:0:{}' WHERE option_name = 'active_plugins';");
```

it seems to work without an errors.

Comment: what error does it generate?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL statement near "SET".

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `$wpdb->prefix` instead:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query("UPDATE ". $wpdb->prefix ."options SET option_value = 'a:0:{}' WHERE option_name = 'active_plugins';");
```

You could also check out the tables, to see if the options table is there:

```
print_r($wpdb->tables);
print_r($wpdb->ms_global_tables);
print_r($wpdb->global_tables);
print_r($wpdb->old_tables);
```

Normally it should work to use `$wpdb->options`, so you should check if there is a problem with other table names as well.